# Cutting x pixels from an image

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation

Why this is creating many images instead of just two?

```
convert input-image.jpg -crop 28x +repage monet_vertical_%d.jpg
```

I want to get two images; 28 pixels from the base and another image with what's left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   convert $f -gravity South  -crop 0x28+0+0 +repage label.jpg
   convert $f -gravity South  -chop  0x28  not-labeled.jpg
```